# Is it Possible to Use Casting as "array slicing" in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, ranged-loops

I have some shared memory populated by specialized hardware.  It's declared as an array of structs, like:

```
struct port {
    int data[10];
    char port_id[8];
}

struct bus {
    port ports[5];
    char bus_id[8];
}

struct bus busses[10];
```

I'm (re)learning C++, and wanted to use C++11's ranged for loops to iterate over the data.

HOWEVER: That last dimension of the array (`data[10]`), I only care about the first 4 elements.  Is there a way to take a slice of the data and use it in the for() statement?

Like

```
for (auto & b : busses) {
    for (auto & p : bus.ports) {
        for (auto & d : port.data[0 through 3]) {
             store_the_address_of_d_for_use_elsewhere(d);
        }
     }
 }
```

Is there a way to use a cast in the innermost for loop, so that it appears like there's only 4 elements?  The address of the data is important because I'm going to refer directly to it later using pointers.

Comment: What is `int bus[10]port[5]data[10]` supposed to mean?

Comment: @M.M a simplification of the structs to show the dimensions.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean, it would be better to show real code for the declaration

Comment: I edited the question to clarify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably one of those times when a good old-fashioned `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)` is your best bet.

Don't overthink it, and don't try to use "new" features just for the sake of it, creating more complexity and more work in the process.

Comment: Ultimately, I agree with you, and I went with using a regular for loop.  If the solution was a simple one, it would have pleased my Python-damaged brain to use the new `for` syntax. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class T>
struct array_view {
  T* b = 0;
  T* e = 0;
  T* begin() const { return b; }
  T* end() const { return e; }
  std::size_t size() const { return end()-begin(); }
  T& front() const { return *begin(); }
  T& back() const { return *(end()-1); }

  // basic constructors:
  array_view(T* s, T* f):b(s), e(f) {}
  array_view(T* s, std::size_t N):array_view(s, s+N) {}

  // default ctors: (no need for move)
  array_view()=default;
  array_view(array_view const&)=default;
  array_view& operator=(array_view const&)=default;

  // advanced constructors:
  template<class U>
  using is_compatible = std::integral_constant<bool,
    std::is_same<U, T*>{} || std::is_same<U, T const*>{} ||
    std::is_same<U, T volatile*>{} || std::is_same<U, T volatile const*>{}
  >;
  // this one consumes containers with a compatible .data():
  template<class C,
    typename std::enable_if<is_compatible< decltype(std::declval<C&>().data()) >{}, int>::type = 0
  >
  array_view( C&& c ): array_view( c.data(), c.size() ) {}
  // this one consumes compatible arrays:
  template<class U, std::size_t N,
    typename std::enable_if<is_compatible< U* >{}, int>::type = 0
  >
  array_view( U(&arr)[N] ):
    array_view( arr, N )
  {}

  // create a modified view:
  array_view without_front( std::size_t N = 1 ) const {
    return {begin()+(std::min)(size(), N), end()};
  }
  array_view without_back( std::size_t N = 1 ) const {
    return {begin(), end()-(std::min)(size(), N)};
  }
  array_view only_front( std::size_t N = 1 ) const {
    return {begin(), begin()+(std::min)(size(), N)};
  }
  array_view only_back( std::size_t N = 1 ) const {
    return {end()-(std::min)(size(), N), end()};
  }
};
```

Now some functions that let you easily create it:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
array_view<T> array_view_of( T(&arr)[N] ) {
  return arr;
}
template<class C,
  class Data = decltype( std::declval<C&>().data() ),
  class T = typename std::remove_pointer<Data>::type
>
array_view<T> array_view_of( C&& c ) {
  return std::forward<C>(c);
}
template<class T>
array_view<T> array_view_of( T* s, std::size_t N ) {
  return {s, N};
}
template<class T>
array_view<T> array_view_of( T* s, T* e ) {
  return {s, e};
}
```

and we are done the boilerplate part.

```
for (auto & b : bus) {
  for (auto & p : bus.port) {
    for (auto & d : array_view_of(bus.data).only_front(4)) {
      store_the_address_of_d_for_use_elsewhere(d);
    }
  }
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a675471ef3da87e)

Now I would only advocate this approach because `array_view` is shockingly useful in many different applications.  Writing it just for this case is silly.

Note that the above `array_view` is a multiply-iterated class; I've written it here before.  This one is, in my opinion, better than the previous ones, other than the annoying [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)-isms I had to use.

Comment: That's pretty amazing; I don't think I'm familiar enough yet with C++ (especially C++11) to entirely appreciate everything going on there.  Your  code has inspired me to learn more about the templating system, which is pretty new to me.

Comment: `(std::min)(size(), N)` Is this an attempt to improve diagnostics when a macro `min` is defined, or something else? I'm referring to the encapsulation of the function name within parenthesis.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit On MSVC, `(std::min)(blah, blah)` will work despite the fact that `#define min(a,b) blah` is defined, because the `()` convince MSVC that this isn't a 2-argument macro call.  Elsewhere it is harmless.  So it is ingrained into my coding fingers.  No idea if that is standard preprocessor compliant or not.

Comment: I don't know whether to laugh or cry.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (auto & d : reinterpret_cast<int (&)[4]>(p))
```

Comment: That's a really cool solution.  I've read that using reinterpret_cast can lead to problems, and that some people consider it a bad sign when they see it in code.  Do you know how reliable it is?

Comment: I made [made a fiddle](http://fiddle.jyt.io/github/8b19554f42bf19addf0d5ec5c6cc0cb2) and it works, thanks!

Comment: I don't know how safe this is. Indeed, if I saw it in code, I'd have to question its sanity and that's never a good thing.